# How to set a key in "module" and pass the rest of the keys to "module/subgroup" in l3keys?

Tags: macros, expl3, l3keys

I'm trying to create a `key` to pass the rest of the keys to `/subgroup` based on a boolean condition. That is to say that something like this works:

```
[key in <module>, rest of keys pass to <module/subgroup>]
```

Each `/subgroup` has keys with the same names, my idea is to be able to create a command that works in the following way:

```
\mycmd[key = name (active condition), pass rest of keys acorde to condition to <module/name>]{...}
```

with the code I own, I am able to do this, but it is based on a comparison of strings, is quite weak and fails if not placed in the correct order. 
This is the example file (first attempt):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { mymodule / style-a }
  {
    style-a .bool_set:N = \l_style_a_bool, 
    style-a .initial:n  = false, 
    key-a   .tl_set:N   = \l_style_a_keya_tl, 
    key-b   .tl_set:N   = \l_style_a_keyb_tl
  }

\keys_define:nn { mymodule / style-b }
  {
    style-b .bool_set:N = \l_style_b_bool, 
    style-b .initial:n  = false, 
    key-a   .tl_set:N   = \l_style_b_keya_tl, 
    key-b   .tl_set:N   = \l_style_b_keyb_tl,
  }

\keys_define:nn { mymodule }
  {
    style-a .code:n = \keys_set:nn { mymodule / style-a } { style-a = true },
    style-b .code:n = \keys_set:nn { mymodule / style-b } { style-b = true }
  }

% style-a
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mymodule_style_a:n #1
  {
    This  ~ is ~ \texttt{"#1"} ~ whit ~ \texttt{[key-a ~ = ~ \use:c{l_style_a_keya_tl}]}  ~ 
    and ~ \texttt{[key-b ~ = ~ \use:c{l_style_a_keyb_tl}]} .
  }
% style-b
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mymodule_style_b:n #1
  {
    This  ~ is ~ \texttt{"#1"} ~ whit ~ \texttt{[key-a ~ = ~ \use:c{l_style_b_keya_tl}]}  ~ 
    and ~ \texttt{[key-b ~ = ~ \use:c{l_style_b_keyb_tl}]} .
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mymodule_test_keys:n #1
  {
    \str_case:xnF { \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 1 } }
      {
        { style-a } 
          { 
            \keys_set:nn { mymodule  } { style-a } 
            \keys_set:nn { mymodule / style-a } { #1 }
          }
        { style-b } 
          { 
            \keys_set:nn { mymodule  } { style-b } 
            \keys_set:nn { mymodule / style-b } { #1 }
          }
      }
      {}
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nnF { x }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \mycmd:nn #1#2
  {
    \group_begin:
    \__mymodule_test_keys:n { #1 }
    \bool_if:nT
      {
        \l_style_a_bool
      }
      { \__mymodule_style_a:n { #2 } }
    \bool_if:nT
      {
        \l_style_b_bool
      }
      { \__mymodule_style_b:n { #2 } }
    \group_end:
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycmd}{ o m }
  {
    \mycmd:nn{#1}{#2}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\mycmd[style-a,key-a=value-A,key-b=value-A]{style-a}\par
\mycmd[style-b,key-a=value-B,key-b=value-B]{style-b}
\end{document}
```

My second attempt solves the problems of my first attempt, but, lose the possibility of generating an error message. This is a second example file:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% define bools for keys
\bool_new:N \l_style_a_bool 
\bool_new:N \l_style_b_bool

\keys_define:nn { mymodule / style-a }
  { 
    style   .tl_set:N   = \l_tmpa_tl        , 
    key-a   .tl_set:N   = \l_style_a_keya_tl, 
    key-b   .tl_set:N   = \l_style_a_keyb_tl,
  }

\keys_define:nn { mymodule / style-b }
  { 
    style   .tl_set:N   = \l_tmpa_tl        , 
    key-a   .tl_set:N   = \l_style_b_keya_tl, 
    key-b   .tl_set:N   = \l_style_b_keyb_tl,
  }

\keys_define:nn { mymodule } 
  { 
    style           .choice:                                        ,
    style / style-a .code:n  = { \bool_set_true:N \l_style_a_bool } ,
    style / style-b .code:n  = { \bool_set_true:N \l_style_b_bool } ,
    unknown         .code:n  = {} % 
  }

% style-a
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mymodule_style_a:n #1
  {
    This  ~ is ~ \texttt{"#1"} ~ whit ~ \texttt{[key-a ~ = ~ \use:c{l_style_a_keya_tl}]}  ~ 
    and ~ \texttt{[key-b ~ = ~ \use:c{l_style_a_keyb_tl}]} .
  }
% style-b
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mymodule_style_b:n #1
  {
    This  ~ is ~ \texttt{"#1"} ~ whit ~ \texttt{[key-a ~ = ~ \use:c{l_style_b_keya_tl}]}  ~ 
    and ~ \texttt{[key-b ~ = ~ \use:c{l_style_b_keyb_tl}]} .
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \mycmd:nn #1#2
  {
    \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn { mymodule  } { #1 } 
    \bool_if:nT
      {
        \l_style_a_bool
      }
      { 
        \keys_set:nn { mymodule / style-a } { #1 } 
        \__mymodule_style_a:n {#2}  
      }
    \bool_if:nT
      {
        \l_style_b_bool
      }
      { 
        \keys_set:nn { mymodule / style-b } { #1 } 
        \__mymodule_style_b:n {#2} 
      }
    \group_end:
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycmd}{ o m }
  {
    \mycmd:nn{#1}{#2}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\mycmd[style=style-a,key-a=value-A,key-b=value-A]{style-a}\par
\mycmd[style=style-b,key-a=value-B,key-b=value-B]{style-b}
\end{document}
```

I searched the forum for some adaptive code, but I didn't find any.
Is there any way to do this?

Greetings.

Comment: Which error message are you talking about? There is already one when passing an invalid value for a choice key. In your `\keys_define:nn { mymodule }` (second example), I would use `style / style-a .bool_set:N = ..., style / style-a .initial:n = { false }`, otherwise, you are keeping the value the bool had before calling `\keys_define:nn`, in case the option isn't set in any way (I mean, not passed at all).

Comment: For the “separation”: you could iterate on a `clist` created from the first argument of `\mycmd:nn` and remove every item that starts with `style=` (i.e., you can create an empty `clist` and copy there only the items that don't start with `style=`; I believe you would have to handle optional space tokens on either side of the `=` to be fully correct, maybe also to the left of `style`, so a `regex` could be useful). Regarding the error messages, wouldn't it be enough to use an `unknown` key in `\keys_define:nn { mymodule / style-a }` and `\keys_define:nn { mymodule / style-b }`?

Comment: @frougon: That's exactly what I need, regarding error handling perhaps your idea is better than mine, could you give an example of the use of `cmap/regex`?

Comment: Please see my [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/495617/73317) below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter out a given option from a comma list with the help of `\clist_map_inline:nn` and the `regex` module. In the following example, we filter out all occurrences of the `style` option:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\regex_new:N \l__mymodule_option_regex

% Filter-out all occurrences of keyword argument #1 from comma list #2.
% Store the resulting comma list in #3.
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mymodule_filter_out_option:nnN #1#2#3
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
    \regex_set:Nn \l__mymodule_option_regex { ^ \u{l_tmpa_tl} \ * = }
    \clist_clear:N #3

    \clist_map_inline:nn {#2}
      {
        \regex_match:NnF \l__mymodule_option_regex {##1}
          { \clist_put_right:Nn #3 {##1} }
      }
  }

% Filter-out all occurrences of keyword argument #1 from comma list #2.
% Print the remaining items, one per line.
\NewDocumentCommand \filteroutoption { m m }
  {
    \__mymodule_filter_out_option:nnN {#1} {#2} \l_tmpa_clist
    \clist_use:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { \\ }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \filteroutoption{style}{style=style-a,key-a=value-A,key-b=value-B,
                          foobarstyle = foobarvalue,
                          style   =   other-style, some-key=value,
                          other key = {other, value}, style=foo-style,
                          final key = {its\ \ \ \ value}}
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

In order to use this is in your second example, you can replace:

```latex
\cs_new_protected:Npn \mycmd:nn #1#2
  {
    \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn { mymodule  } { #1 } 
    \bool_if:nT
      {
        \l_style_a_bool
      }
      { 
        \keys_set:nn { mymodule / style-a } { #1 } 
        \__mymodule_style_a:n {#2}  
      }
    \bool_if:nT
      {
        \l_style_b_bool
      }
      { 
        \keys_set:nn { mymodule / style-b } { #1 } 
        \__mymodule_style_b:n {#2} 
      }
    \group_end:
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycmd}{ o m }
  {
    \mycmd:nn{#1}{#2}
  }
```

with:

```latex
\clist_new:N \l__mymodule_tmp_clist

\cs_new_protected:Npn \mymodule_mycmd:nn #1#2
  {
    \group_begin:
    \__mymodule_filter_out_option:nnN { style } {#1} \l__mymodule_tmp_clist

    \keys_set:nn { mymodule } {#1}
    \bool_if:NT \l_style_a_bool
      {
        \keys_set:nV { mymodule / style-a } \l__mymodule_tmp_clist
        \__mymodule_style_a:n {#2}
      }
    \bool_if:NT \l_style_b_bool
      {
        \keys_set:nV { mymodule / style-b } \l__mymodule_tmp_clist
        \__mymodule_style_b:n {#2}
      }
    \group_end:
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \mycmd { O{} m }
  {
    \mymodule_mycmd:nn {#1} {#2}
  }
```

This way, `mymodule / style-a` and `mymodule / style-b` will not receive any `style` key.

Your second example could be changed like this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% define bools for keys (by def false)
\bool_new:N \l_style_a_bool
\bool_new:N \l_style_b_bool

\keys_define:nn { mymodule / style-a }
  {
    key-a   .tl_set:N   = \l_style_a_keya_tl,
    key-b   .tl_set:N   = \l_style_a_keyb_tl,
  }

\keys_define:nn { mymodule / style-b }
  {
    key-a   .tl_set:N   = \l_style_b_keya_tl,
    key-b   .tl_set:N   = \l_style_b_keyb_tl,
  }

\keys_define:nn { mymodule }
  {
    style            .choice:                                        ,
    % Remember to set the bools to their default value before using
    % a \keys_set-like function here (alas, .bool_set:N \l_style_*_bool
    % doesn't seem to be accepted here).
    style / style-a  .code:n  = { \bool_set_true:N \l_style_a_bool } ,
    style / style-b  .code:n  = { \bool_set_true:N \l_style_b_bool } ,
  }

% style-a
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mymodule_style_a:n #1
  {
    This  ~ is ~ \texttt{"#1"} ~ with ~ \texttt{[key-a ~ = ~ \use:c{l_style_a_keya_tl}]}  ~
    and ~ \texttt{[key-b ~ = ~ \use:c{l_style_a_keyb_tl}]} .
  }

% style-b
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mymodule_style_b:n #1
  {
    This  ~ is ~ \texttt{"#1"} ~ with ~ \texttt{[key-a ~ = ~ \use:c{l_style_b_keya_tl}]}  ~
    and ~ \texttt{[key-b ~ = ~ \use:c{l_style_b_keyb_tl}]} .
  }

\msg_new:nnn { mymodule } { unknown-style }
  {
   The ~ choice ~ passed ~ to ~ key  ~ [style]  ~  is ~ not ~ valid.  ~
   Valid ~ choices ~ are: ~ style-a, ~ style-b.
  }

\tl_new:N \l__mymodule_styles_tl
% Filter-out all occurrences of keyword argument #1 from comma list #2.
% Store the resulting comma list in #3.
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mymodule_filter_out_option:nnN #1#2#3
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
    \regex_set:Nn \l__mymodule_option_regex { ^ \u{l_tmpa_tl} \ * = }
    \clist_clear:N #3

    \clist_map_inline:nn {#2}
      {
        \regex_match:NnF \l__mymodule_option_regex {##1}
          { \clist_put_right:Nn #3 {##1} }
      }
  }

\clist_new:N \l__mymodule_tmp_clist

\cs_new_protected:Npn \mymodule_mycmd:nn #1#2
  {
    \group_begin:

    \bool_set_false:N \l_style_a_bool
    \bool_set_false:N \l_style_b_bool
    \keys_set_known:nn { mymodule } {#1}

    \__mymodule_filter_out_option:nnN { style } {#1} \l__mymodule_tmp_clist

    \bool_if:NT \l_style_a_bool
      {
        \keys_set:nV { mymodule / style-a } \l__mymodule_tmp_clist
        \__mymodule_style_a:n {#2}
      }
    \bool_if:NT \l_style_b_bool
      {
        \keys_set:nV { mymodule / style-b } \l__mymodule_tmp_clist
        \__mymodule_style_b:n {#2}
      }
    \group_end:
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \mycmd { O{} m }
  {
    \mymodule_mycmd:nn {#1} {#2}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
% check with valid keys
\mycmd[style=style-a,key-a=value-A,key-b=value-A]{style-a}\par
\mycmd[key-a=value-B,key-b=value-B,style=style-b]{style-b}
% Uncomment to show error :)
%\mycmd[foobarstyle=style-aandotherthings, style=style-a,key-a=value-A,key-b=value-A]{style-a}\par
%\mycmd[style=style-c,key-a=value-B,key-b=value-B]{style-b}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've made a little correction (added a `^` regex metacharacter) to make sure we *don't* filter out items such as `blablastyle=...`.

Comment: Great, I will try to place it in my second example ...

Comment: Using `\__mymodule_filter_out_option:nnN {style} {〈options〉} \l__your_clist` where `〈options〉` contains the user-provided options will store into `\l__your_clist` exactly what you want to process (〈options〉 with all `style=` options filtered out). Note: you have to declare `\l__your_clist` yourself.

Comment: Please see my last edit. Look carefully: I simplified the `\bool_if` tests, renamed your `\mycmd:nn` function and replaced the `o` option specifier for `\mycmd` with `O{}`, in addition to passing `\mycmd`'s first argument to `mymodule / style-a`  and `mymodule / style-b` with `style` options filtered out.

Comment: Ok, I tried it, I commented `%style` in `mymodule / style-a` and `mymodule / style-b` and everything goes OK, but, if I comment `unknown` in `mymodule` fails, that is to say, it doesn't go as I would like. It may be necessary to add a second `list|regex` to save the `style=` values and pass them to `mymodule` using `\keys_set:nn { mymodule } } { \clist_item: \l_tmpa_clist {1} }` ( I don't want `style=val` to be repeated in the options). I don't know if that's possible.

Comment: That would be `\keys_set:nx`, not `\keys_set:nn`, but this seems complicated and not very useful. When you pass `style=style-a,〈options〉` as first argument to `\mycmd`, all `〈options〉` can now easily be validated by `mymodule/style-a`. All that remains to validate is the value passed for the `style` key. This is trivial to do with `style/unknown .code:n = ...` in `\keys_define:nn { mymodule } { ... }` . You should remove the `unknown` pseudo-key (as opposed to `style/unknown`) in this `...`, it isn't useful at all—everything will be validated with what I said in this comment.

Comment: Right, my mistake; but this works if you replace `\keys_set:nn { mymodule }` with `\keys_set_known:nn { mymodule }`.

Comment: I've modified the code to what I left on top (I'll remove it later). Now if I can say that it works as I want, I hope it is written correctly. I only hope that my code is correct, I will be attentive to your comments. Greetings and thanks.

Comment: Please see my last edit. You forgot to pick my latest regex changes (addition of `^`...), but the biggest problem is that your added `\regex_extract_all` is not selective enough. For instance, it will filter out `foobarstyle=style-aandotherthings` which is *not* a `style` option. As a consequence, no error will be reported for this invalid option. This doesn't happen with the code I posted. Notice that my regex applies to individual items *after* `\clist_map_inline` has split them (and done brace + space removal); [to be continued]

Comment: [continuation of the previous comment] yours applies to the whole option list; thus, to be correct, it would also have to handle brace removal, etc. as `\keys_set:nn` and `\clist_map_inline` do. That sounds too fragile, I prefer letting `\clist_map_inline` do this work for me.

Comment: Less serious: your modified `\__mymodule_filter_out_option:nnN` could have had a `#4` parameter for `\l__mymodule_styles_tl` like my `#3`, so that what gets modified is clearly visible wherever the function is called. But since my code in last edit doesn't use this `\l__mymodule_styles_tl` at all, this is just a comment on code clarity.

Comment: You're absolutely right, your implementation is much better than mine. My idea when using `\regex_extract_all:nNTF` and then `\seq_item:N\l_tmpa_seq {1}` was to be more "restrictive" with `style` key,  and prevent it from repeating itself, thus preventing the `bool` variable from being activated more than once and running the code incorrectly (`l3keys` doesn't have a direct option to avoid key repetition). If I read the documentation well, `\bool_new:N`is false by default ((`\bool_set_false:N` is not necessary), I will move my code in favor of yours (and delete some comments). Saludos

Comment: I know `\bool_new:N` makes the bool false, this is just a precaution in case the bool was set by code in an enclosing scope of the `\keys_set_known` call. I don't have time to look at the rest of your comment now. If there is something to add, I will, but not now. :)

Comment: If you want to prevent `style` from being passed several times, it should be possible by testing `\l_style_a_bool` and `\l_style_b_bool` in the `code:n` bits that do `\bool_set_true:N \l_style_a_bool` and `\bool_set_true:N \l_style_b_bool`, but I think I wouldn't clutter the code with such tests for something that doesn't sound very important (well, unless your code has thousands of users ;-).

Comment: The truth is I'm getting complicated by myself, the bad habit of thinking that `key=val` is equal to `getopt`. Again grateful for the time invested. Until next time...